# How to "bubble up" nuget packages so I don't have to double reference?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have a netstandard 2.0 library that I pack into a nuget package, lets call it A. I reference another package in this library, lets call this package B.

**EDIT (more info):** Package B relies on other nuget packages which are ported c++ code via SWIG. When I reference these packages within package B, .dll, .dylib, and .so files are installed alongside the source code of package B. When the runtime error occurs in my netcore app, these are the files that "can't be found"

Then, I write a netcore app which references package A. However, when I try to execute this app, I get a runtime error saying it cant find the methods for package B. So then I must reference the nuget package B directly in the netcore .csproj file. I dont make any calls directly to code within package B from my netcore app. They are method calls which are abstracted through package A which relies on code from package B.

My question is simple, how do change my .csproj files so that I don't have to explicitly reference package B in my netcore .csproj file? Like my title suggests, how can I "bubble up" package B so I don't have to reference it again in my net core app?

Example .csproj files for clarity:

*netstandard library*

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Title>My library A</Title>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="some_c++_SWIG" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

*netcore app*

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Title>My netcore app</Title>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="A" Version="1.0.0" />

    <!-- Why do I have to include B and SWIG pkg again??? -->
    <PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="some_c++_SWIG" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

*project.assets.json*

```
".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1": {
  "B/1.0.0": {
    "type": "package",
    "dependencies": {
    "another_package": "1.0.0"
  },
    "compile": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/B.dll": {}
  },
    "runtime": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/B.dll": {}
  }
},

    ...

"libraries": {
  "B/1.0.0": {
    "sha512": "abc123",
    "type": "package",
    "path": "B/1.0.0",
    "files": [
      ".nupkg.metadata",
      "B.1.0.0.nupkg.sha512",
      "B.nuspec",
      "lib/netstandard2.0/B.dll"
    ]
  },

    ...

"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp2.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "B": {
        "target": "Package",
        "version": "[1.0.0, )"
      },
```

Here is an example error message:
(where c_csharp_metrics has a .dll, .dylib, and .so file that is installed/referenced within package B)

```
Encountered exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'c_csharp_metricsPINVOKE' threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception. --->
 System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'c_csharp_metrics’ or one of its dependencies. 
In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: 
libc_csharp_metrics: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at c_csharp_metricsPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_c_csharp_metrics(ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate nullReferenceDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate outOfMemoryDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate overflowDelegate, 
ExceptionDelegate systemExceptionDelegate)
   at c_csharp_metricsPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at c_csharp_metricsPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..ctor()
   at c_csharp_metricsPINVOKE..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at c_csharp_metricsPINVOKE.new_metrics__SWIG_0()
   at metrics..ctor()
```

Comment: This strange. Do the versions match?

Comment: I'm using the same version of package B in both the library and the app.

Comment: What you desire is how it is supposed to work in my experience. If you look at the nuspec for package A does it contain a dependency on B? Also you say it can't find the methods? What is the specific error? This could actually be a problem related to versioning since it is a runtime error.

Comment: Another thought is that package B is doing something with the build output folder like copying other dependencies there and whatever it is, it isn't flowed down to indirect dependencies like your app when it doesn't have package reference.

Comment: Please show the contents of the netcore app's `obj/projects.assets.json` file. Package `B` should be a transient dependency, and the assets file will show if it is, and if not, why.

Comment: @DavidOwens in your `project.assets.json` file, you missed the part about package `A`. In any case you see in the part that you copied that package `B` lists dependencies in the first `targets` section of the assets file (you also cut out `targets:` from your sample). By finding package `A` in the targets section, you can check its dependencies to see if package `B` is indeed listed as a dependency.